Is "logic connect 4" the official name of this connect 4 variant?
Do you know the real name of this game called "logic connect 4"?
I've found this at makerworld which is a 3D print group, but it seems that it's not the real name of the game.


Its sounds like a variant to "connect 4", why do you think it's not the real name of the variant?

Probably because it seemed off. "logic" is not a fitting descriptor without the "orbital" part. No need to downvote on that basis (especially since it turns out the OP's instincts were correct).

"Official" would require a context of a publisher or governing body. But if you mean "original" (i.e., as named by its creator), then no. It was published 10 days earlier on the same site by what appears to be its creator as
轨道逻辑四子棋 Track Logic Connect Four Chess
The first part of which google translates to "Orbital Logic Tetra". That model, with rules that were described in the page as being "introduced" with the publication of the model, was created by 我的妹妹最可爱 (@YDlong).

It was released under Creative Commons Attribution-Noncommercial-Share Alike (unlike the "Logic Connect 4" derivation, which says "This work is licensed under a Standard Digital File License." and without, as far as I can tell, the attribution required by YDlong's publication).
Note that the English translation of the rules on that page is flawed. It says "four pieces on the board after move 3" (which is clearly nonsensical). The correct translation is "A player with four pieces in a row on the board after the third step wins."
Game play:

move an opponent's piece to an adjacent (empty) space.
place your own piece on any empty space.
push the center to cause the pieces to rotate.


If you've upvoted this answer, please consider upvoting the question as well.
